# call command after animate command is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I want to know how can i call up the 2nd line after the animate function is done? Now the 2nd line starts before the animate function is done.

Can someone help me?

```
$(".intro").animate({height:'100%', width:'100%'}, 6000);
$(".intro").append("<div class='text'>Some Text</div>")
$(".text").css({"background":"#FFFF00" , "height":"23px","width":"300px","position":"absolute","top":"0","left":"0","bottom":"0","left":"0","margin":"auto"});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code snippet - add a callback.

**Complete Function** : If supplied, the complete callback function is fired once the animation is complete.

```
$(".intro").animate({height:'100%', width:'100%'}, 6000, function(){
    $(this).append("<div class='text'>Some Text</div>");
});
```

Refer this **[Link: .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** for More examples.

Comment: thans for your answer. You helped me alot :)

Answer (score 1):

Use callback function for `animate`:

```
$(".intro")
   .animate(
       {height:'100%',width:'100%'},
       6000,
       function(){
           $(".intro").append("<div class='text'>Some Text</div>");
       }
    );
```